# scrollView with paging enabled not working properly ? (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i want to create paging scrollView with three UIViews. And than wants to add imageView as a subView to these UIViews. i cant figure it out how to calculate the frame of imageViews. 
When i run the code without imageViews it works perfectly fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;

    NSArray *colorsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor blueColor], [UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor greenColor], nil];

    NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"123.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"13.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < colorsArray.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.size = self.view.frame.size;

        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        view.backgroundColor = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [view addSubview:imageView];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:view];

    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * colorsArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.bounds);
    CGFloat pageFraction = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = roundf(pageFraction);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame for the image view needs to be relative to its superview (i.e. view) not the scroll view. To achieve the paging you desire change:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
```

to:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: This should be:  `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];`

Comment: @cetcet what if you applied a rotation transform to your image? You might not want bounds in that instance. But yes in most situations, you could make that substitution.